# What option argument can I give to `cpulimit -l` when I want a process to have unlimit cpu usage?

Tags: cpu, cpu-usage, cpulimit

In cpulimit

> -l, --limit=N
>
> percentage of CPU allowed from 1 up. Usually 1 - 100, but can be
>   higher on multi-core CPUs. (mandatory)

What option argument can I give to `-l` when I want a process to have no limit on cpu usage?

Is it `$(($(nproc)*100))`?

(I am writing a script, which accepts a command line argument and assigns it as an option argument to `-l`. In case the command line argument is not specified to the script, I would like to provide a default value, which represents no limit.)

Thanks.

Comment: When I want no limit, I don't start `cpulimit` in the first place. What's good in running the tool in this situation?

Comment: Tim, IMHO it can be up to `<number of cores>*100`

Answer (score 1):

Based on Kamil's comment (don't use cpulimit when not needed), I would just do domething like this in your script:

```
cmd=<command you want to run>

limit=<your cpu limit. can be empty>

if [ -z "$limit" ]; then
    cpulimit_cmd=""
else
    cpulimit_cmd="cpulimit -l $limit"
fi

$cpulimit_cmd $cmd
```